# Remainder When N divided by 2^M

Tags: code-golf, restricted-source

Write the shortest code to find the remainder when an input number N is divided by 2^M. You cannot use /,* and % operator.

```
Input Specification
Number of test cases followed by a pair of integers on each line.

Sample Input
1
150 6

Sample Output
22

Limits
1<T<1000
1<N<2^31
1<B<31

Time Limit
1 Sec
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Golfscript - 16 chars

```
~]1>2/{~2\?(&n}/
```

For a single pair or numbers this would sufficient

```
~2\?(&
```

By the way, the `/` does not stand for division here :)

Answer (score 3):

```
scanf("%d", &T);
while(T--){
   scanf("%d,%d", &N,&M);
   printf("%d",N&~(~0 << M));
}
```

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: Can't you C? ;)

Answer (score 3):

Uh, guys, in pretty much any language, it would be

```
N & (1 << M  - 1)
```

Comment: Except M should be B and you forgot the code to read the input and loop through each case and write out the answer

Comment: @gnibbler, I think the point is that's it's a super-boring question.

Comment: @Peter, super-boring is rot13 or reversing stdin. This question isn't _that_ bad by comparison

Comment: @gnibbler, it's on a par with factorial, and I don't think those two are separated from rot13 by more than a hair. Reversing stdin requires using a stack in most languages, but even so I don't think it's a worthwhile question either.

Comment: I don't think it's *boring*, I just think there's a canonically correct answer to the underlying math problem.  The problems around looping and printing *are* boring, or at least pointless, because that's not the way coding challenges present themselves in real life.

Answer (score 1):

## Java

With whitespace to make readable:

```
long F(long M, long N) {
  M = 2<<M;
  while(N>=M) N-=M;
  return N;
}
```

Comment: That would be too slow. :)

Comment: @fR0DDY You didn't specify any time constraints.

Comment: @marcog Ya! I am sorry about that.

Comment: Java (if I remember correctly).

Answer (score 1):

### Perl, 31

```
<>;/ /,say($`&~(-1<<$'))while<>
```

Perl 5.10 or later, run with `perl -E '<code here>'`

Answer (score 0):

## J, <s>15</s> <s>12</s> 9 bytes

6 bytes thanks to [@miles](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/6710/miles).

```
#.@#:~#&2
```

### Previous 12-byte version

```
#.@({.~-)~#:
```

#### Usage

```
>> f =: #.@({.~-)~#:
>> 6 f 150
<< 22
```

Where `>>` is STDIN and `<<` is STDOUT.

#### Explanation

`#:` converts `n` to base 2.

`({.~-)~` then takes the last `m` digits from it

`#.` converts it back to base 2.

### Previous 15-byte version:

```
2#.(0-[){.[:#:]
```

#### Usage

```
>> f =: 2#.(0-[){.[:#:]
>> 6 f 150
<< 22
```

Where `>>` is STDIN and `<<` is STDOUT.

#### Explanation

`[:#:]` converts `n` to base 2.

`(0-[){.` then takes the last `m` digits from it

`2#.` converts it back to base 2.

Comment: Using hooks, I've got `#.@({.~-)~#:` for 12 bytes.

Comment: Isn't the `#.` dyadic here?

Comment: No, it is used afterwards. For example, `x f@g y = f (x g y)` but something like `x f&g y = (g x) f (g y)`.

Comment: Another approach is `#.@#:~#&2` for 9 bytes which creates `k` copies of 2 and uses that to create a base 2 representation of `n` for the last `k` binary digits, and converts it back to base 10. Used as `150 (#.@#:~#&2) 6`  which outputs 22.

Comment: Why don't you post that as a separate answer :)

Answer (score 0):

## Racket (scheme) 29 bytes

Kinda cheating because racket doesn't even have the % operator:

```
(λ(n m)(modulo n(expt 2 m)))
```

Answer (score 0):

## SmileBASIC, 36 characters

```
INPUT N,M?N AND(1<<M)-1
```

There's basically only one solution to this...